# Delay On IPad When Calling From A Background Thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am converting my IPhone app to IPad and I'm having an issue with the conversion. I have a background thread that creates some thumbnails.

The problem seems to be that the app loops though the array and outputs all the items but only the last item seems to be loading with the UIButton text present. There is a 5-15 second delay before all the previous buttons have there text displayed.

```
UIImage *tmp = [self thumbnailImage:[effect objectAtIndex:0] thumbnailType:@"category"];

for (id effect in effectArray) {

    UIImage *tmp = [self thumbnailImage:[effect objectAtIndex:0] thumbnailType:@"category"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        UIView *effectView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(item_x_axis, current_row_height, item_width, item_height)];

        UIImageView *imagepreview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [imagepreview setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)];
        [imagepreview setImage:tmp];
        imagepreview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imagepreview.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        imagepreview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        imagepreview.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
        imagepreview.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
        imagepreview.clipsToBounds = NO;
        [effectView addSubview:imagepreview];

        if([[effect objectAtIndex:3]  isEqualToString:@"iap"]){

            UIImageView *buttonPlus = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            [buttonPlus setFrame:CGRectMake(54, 66, 23, 23)];
            [buttonPlus setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonPlus.png"]];
            [effectView addSubview:buttonPlus];

        }

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString([effect objectAtIndex:1]) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button setTitle:[effect objectAtIndex:2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, item_width, item_height);
        button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
        [button setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)];
        [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(120, 0, 0.0, 0.0)];
        [effectView addSubview:button];


        [self.viewScrollCategories addSubview:effectView];

        button = nil;

    });

    if(current_items_per_row < 3){
        current_items_per_row++;
        item_x_axis = item_x_axis + item_width;
    }else {
        current_row_height = current_row_height + item_height;
        current_items_per_row = 1;
        item_x_axis = 0;
    }

}
```

Any idea how to solve this issue? it seemed to work fine on the IPhone.

**EDIT**

This is the code that is calling the background thread (shortned)

```
- (void)imagePickerController:( UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *)info {


//[self generatingThumbnailMessageShow];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self loadAllEffects];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self generatingThumbnailMessageHide];
    });
});

}
```

Comment: Hmm. Let me ask you this. Why are you dropping into a background thread in the first place? Is there something here that takes a really long time?

Comment: Yeah, the image editing takes a long time. The thread generates edited images using different effects and there are 20+ effects so it takes a second or two to edit all the images and produce the thumbnails.

Comment: Well, looking over your code, it seems to me that what you're doing on the main thread should be really fast: you are just creating some subviews and sticking them into the interface. So the delay you are experiencing might be coming from the image editing.

Comment: You should use Instruments to figure out what's actually occupying the time here. It's hard to optimize if you don't know what you're trying to optimize for.

Comment: Hang on, I've got another answer coming up...

Comment: @matt sorry there was a line missing at the start. This is now included.

Comment: The thing is that this runs perfectly on the IPhone and is just slower on the IPad.

Comment: Well, as I said before, they are different devices. I've got an iPad with a single core and an iPhone with a dual core. I would certainly expect that this code would work very differently on those two devices, because the dual core device can truly do multithreading. As I said, don't guess, don't thrash. Whip out Instruments and analyze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are *asking* for a delay with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...`. That code means "Please do this whenever you have time, sometime after my current code finishes running." Once you say that, you are basically saying you don't care when this code runs. You hope it will be some time pretty soon, but you've left the runtime to take care of the details.

So perhaps it is this "hope" that is the issue. The architecture of the device processors is different and the threading model for the device might change the way the device responds to having a bunch of these delayed requests piling up.

I'm not at all clear on what you're trying to accomplish in this code (sorry, `tl:dr`) but the use of delayed performance in the middle of it and your complaint that there is a " 5-15 second delay" seem to go together somehow...

EDIT: OK, I see now that your code is running in the background and you are using `dispatch_async` to step out to the main thread in order to modify the interface. So perhaps the problem is *not* in the code you quote, but in the code you are using to manage your background threading in the first place.

ANOTHER EDIT: Just a wild and crazy idea here. If what takes time is the image processing, why don't you do *all* the image processing and then do your interface updating on the main thread *once*? What I mean is, you're doing this:

```
for (id effect in effectArray) {
    UIImage *tmp = // ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // ...
        [imagepreview setImage:tmp];
```

So you're getting back on the main thread repeatedly each time through the loop. Why not try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    for (id effect in effectArray) {
        UIImage *tmp = // ...
        // ...
        [imagepreview setImage:tmp];
```

Now you're just getting back on the main thread *once*. There will be a delay while the images process, but then interface should just update, badda bing badda boom (technical programming term).

Comment: Hi, please see the above question, I have edited it to show the code that is calling the background thread. I am basically loading an image and showing a "creating thumbnail" message. The background thread runs the thumbnail code and then when it is complete the message is removed.

Comment: Nice idea and it seems to have worked. I ended up creating an empty array and then looping through the images and adding them to the array. I then placed the second loop to process the thumbnails inside the main_thread call and then looped through and matched the current index to the index in the image array. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wow, not bad considering I was pretty much flying blind on this one! :) Yeah, threading is *hard*. In addition to the speed issues you should be very, very careful.